# automapper : map one object to many

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper

I have the following domain model (one class):

```
public class DriverDomain
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public int? TruckId { get; set; }

    public int? TrailerId { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int? UnitNo { get; set; }

    public int? GpsId { get; set; }

    public string CompanyFEIN { get; set; }

    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public string CompanyAddress { get; set; }

    public string CompanyCity { get; set; }

    public string CompanyZIP { get; set; }

    public string CompanyState { get; set; }

    public System.DateTime? DOB { get; set; }

    public string SSN { get; set; }

    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }

    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public string State { get; set; }

    public string ZIP { get; set; }

    public string DLno { get; set; }

    public string Dlstate { get; set; }

    public System.DateTime? DLexp { get; set; }

    public System.DateTime? MedExp { get; set; }

    public System.DateTime? HireDate { get; set; }

    public System.DateTime? TermDate { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public bool DrugTest { get; set; }

    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public string CardNo { get; set; }

    public string EmployeeNo { get; set; }

    public bool? OwnerOp { get; set; }

    public bool OccAcc { get; set; }

    public decimal? WeeklyOccAcc { get; set; }

    public bool Ifta { get; set; }

    public decimal? WeeklyIfta { get; set; }

    public bool TrailerRental { get; set; }

    public decimal? WeeklyTrailerRent { get; set; }

    public bool CargoIns { get; set; }

    public decimal? WeeklyCargoIns { get; set; }

    public decimal? PilotRebate { get; set; }

    public bool OnlineAccess { get; set; }

    public int? OnlineId { get; set; }

    public bool ViewedSchedule { get; set; }

    public int SchedulePriority { get; set; }

    public bool Hourly { get; set; }

    public decimal? HourlyPay { get; set; }

    public string IpassTransponderId { get; set; }

    public System.DateTime? RecordDate { get; set; }

    public string RecordChangedBy { get; set; }

    public string EmgcontactName { get; set; }

    public string EmgcontactPhone { get; set; }

    public string EmgcontactRelationship { get; set; }

    public string Nickname { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public string AspNetUserName { get; set; }

    public string AvatarUrl { get; set; }

    public bool PaidByPercent { get; set; }

    public decimal? PercentPaid { get; set; }

    public bool PaidByMile { get; set; }

    public decimal? PayPerMile { get; set; }

    public bool CompanyPlates { get; set; }

    public decimal? WeeklyPlateCharge { get; set; }

    public bool EnableEscrowDeductionOnPayroll { get; set; }

    public decimal WeeklyEscrowDeduction { get; set; }

    public bool ShowPersonalConveyance { get; set; } = false;

    public bool ShowYardMoves { get; set; } = false;

    public string StartTimeOfDay { get; set; } = "00:00:00.000";
}
```

and many view model classes, each of them can be mapped to this domain class:

```
public class DriverPersonalInfoVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public System.DateTime? DOB { get; set; }

    public string SSN { get; set; }

    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
```

...

```
public class DriverEmploymentVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public System.DateTime? HireDate { get; set; }

    public System.DateTime? TermDate { get; set; }

    public bool DrugTest { get; set; }

    public bool OnlineAccess { get; set; }

    public bool ViewedSchedule { get; set; }
```

map rules:

```
        CreateMap<Domain.POCO.Driver.DriverDomain, DriverPersonalInfoVM>();
        CreateMap<Domain.POCO.Driver.DriverDomain, DriverEmploymentVM>();
        CreateMap<Domain.POCO.Driver.DriverDomain, DriverPayrollVM>();
        CreateMap<Domain.POCO.Driver.DriverDomain, DriverCompensationVM>();
        CreateMap<Domain.POCO.Driver.DriverDomain, DriverFuelTollsVM>();
        CreateMap<Domain.POCO.Driver.DriverDomain, DriverAvatarVM>();
```

it works fine.
But now I have the following view model class:

```
public class DriverEditVM
{
    public DriverEditVM(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
        PersonalInfo = new DriverPersonalInfoVM { Id = id };
        Employment = new DriverEmploymentVM { Id = id };
        Payroll = new DriverPayrollVM { Id = id };
        Compensation = new DriverCompensationVM { Id = id };
        FuelTolls = new DriverFuelTollsVM { Id = id };
        Avatar = new DriverAvatarVM { Id = id };
    }

    public DriverPersonalInfoVM PersonalInfo { get; set; }
    public DriverEmploymentVM Employment { get; set; }
    public DriverPayrollVM Payroll { get; set; }
    public DriverCompensationVM Compensation { get; set; }
    public DriverFuelTollsVM FuelTolls { get; set; }
    public DriverAvatarVM Avatar { get; set; }
}
```

and map rule:

```
        CreateMap<Domain.POCO.Driver.DriverDomain, DriverEditVM>();
```

but when I try to map domain object to DriverEditVM:

```
            var driver = _driverService.GetDriver(id.Value);
            DriverEditVM model = mapper.Map<DriverEditVM>(driver);
```

I have empty properties PersonalInfo, Employment etc. How to map it?

Answer (score 0):

As you have created maps for all your other view models that form part of your `DriverEditVM`, you should be able to do this:

```
CreateMap<Domain.POCO.Driver.DriverDomain, DriverEditVM>()
    .ForAllMembers(opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));
```

**Edit**

As some members are not being mapped, there are two approaches, explicitly ignore the un-mapped members or explicitly map the mapped members:

```
CreateMap<Domain.POCO.Driver.DriverDomain, DriverEditVM>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.IgnoredProperty1, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(dest => dest.IgnoredProperty2, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForAllOtherMembers(opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));
```

Or

```
CreateMap<Domain.POCO.Driver.DriverDomain, DriverEditVM>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.PersonalInfo, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Employment, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Payroll, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Compensation, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.FuelTolls, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Avatar, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src))
    .ForAllOtherMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Answer (score -1):

Solved this problem :

```
        CreateMap<Domain.POCO.Driver.DriverDomain, DriverEditVM>()
            .ForMember(p => p.PersonalInfo, p => p.MapFrom(src => src))
            .ForMember(p => p.Avatar, p => p.MapFrom(src => src))
            .ForMember(p => p.Compensation, p => p.MapFrom(src => src))
            .ForMember(p => p.Employment, p => p.MapFrom(src => src))
            .ForMember(p => p.FuelTolls, p => p.MapFrom(src => src))
            .ForMember(p => p.Payroll, p => p.MapFrom(src => src))
            ;
```